# a way to have a Raspberry Pi wait for a command

Tags: python, linux, networking, webserver, raspberry-pi

I have searched around for an answer to this question but don't really know what to search and where to look. I've mainly done basic web development so I'm new to making applications on different computers talk to each other.

I want to know the best and most efficient way to have a raspberry Pi sit and wait for a command from another computer on the same local network.

I have stared a small project to get the Pi's camera to start and stop recording when commands are sent from a computer on the same local network. I currently have a small python script which starts and stops recording video to a file when two different buttons are clicked however I want to change the button triggers into a command from another computer. The Pi could be idle for a few days at a time and then a command comes in to record. So what is the most efficient way to get this to happen. I have a few thoughts/question and I would like to know everyone's thoughts.

- Do I need to install a web server?
- Is it possible to sleep the pi and
  have it wake on LAN?
- Should I open a socket and put a loop in the
  python script to constantly check for messages? Is this energy
  efficient?
- Should I send a message from the computer to start the python script with a shell script then send the start and stop commands?

As you can see, with my limited knowledge of having applications interact I'm all over the place as to knowing what my options are. Thanks for reading and I'm looking forward to answers...

Comment: Unfortunately I only know the 2nd most efficient way so cannot answer your question ;_;

Comment: 2nd most efficient way would do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import socket
host="0.0.0.0"
port=43210 #or some high number unused port
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
s.bind((host,port)) 
s.listen(1)
client,address = s.accept()
#this wont run until after something hits that port
```

then on the other computer just goto

```
http://ip.of.raspery.pi:43210
```

that will attempt to open the port ... the webpage wont load but the pi should do whatever is below that comment

alternatively you could do

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/start")
def start():
   return "OK START"
@app.route("/stop")
def stop():
  return "OK STOP!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run("0.0.0.0",port=8080)
```

and run it on the pi ... (or even better serve it through apache... but thats another question)

then you can navigate to

```
http://raspberry.pi.ip:8080/start 
http://raspberry.pi.ip:8080/stop
```

this time you will see a status message

Comment: Also, `import socket`

Comment: Thanks @JoranBeasley, which line means that it will it not run until something connects to it? Is it `s.listen(1)`?

Comment: the `accept` is what blocks ... listen tells how many pending connections to allow in the queue (basically)

Comment: if you want to do more than just continue (ie have commands of some sort) then you will have some more work to do